# Capturar KeyboardInterrupt

Tags: python, python-3.x, excepciones

Estoy haciendo una `aplicación cli` y necesito capturar un `KeyboardInterrupt`
en cualquier punto de la ejecución del programa.

> Mi intención es eliminar algunas carpetas/archivos que hayan podido
>   ser generados.

¿Hay alguna solución `cross-platform`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te he comprendido, podrías usar el módulo [`signal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html) de la biblioteca estándar que nos permite capturar ciertos eventos de forma asíncrona. Aunque hay algunos detalles de este módulo que no son cross-plataform, en este caso  no tendrías problemas.

Si que es importante tener en cuenta que solo se puede usar en el hilo principal si usaras una aplicación multihilos.

Este sería un ejemplo simple:

```
import signal
import sys
import time

# Función que se ejecutará cuando el evento tenga lugar.
def keyboard_interrupt(signal, frame):
    print('Has precionado Ctrl + c')
    sys.exit(0) # Si quieres detener la ejecución

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, keyboard_interrupt)


def run():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

Comment: Iba a eliminar la pregunta, ya que buscando en el foro en Inglés había encontrado esto mismamente (A veces me precipito demasiado). Finalmente he usado este método. También he usado `functools.partial` para pasarle al handler los ficheros que debe de cerrar antes de eliminar la carpeta con los ficheros dentro. Gracias como siempre y saludos =)