# Error al escribir en fichero, no se puede concatenar str a bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, archivo, socket, tcp

He echo un simple servidor tcp en Python y lo que quiero hacer es guardar los mensajes del cliente en un fichero de texto.

Lo que pasa es que cuando lo intento me pone que no se puede concatenar bytes a string.

¿Sabrían como se puede hacer? Este es el código del servidor:

```
import socket
file=open("mensajes.txt","w+")

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("127.0.0.1", 5550))
s.listen(5)
while True:
    sc, addr = s.accept()
    while True:
        recibido = sc.recv(1024)
        file.write(recibido+"\n")

        print ("Recibido: ", recibido,"utf-8".decode("ascii"))
        nuestra_respuesta = input("Tu: ")
        sc.send(nuestra_respuesta.encode('utf-8'))

file.close()
print ("Adios")
sc.close()
s.close()
```

y este es el error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "clientpyhton.py", line 11, in 
>           file.write(recibido+"\n")
>   TypeError: can't concat str to bytes

Answer (score 1):

Primero de todo, al menos con lo que muestras no tienes implementado un método para salir de forma correcta del ciclo infinito y cerrar tanto el socket como el archivo de forma correcta. Puedes usar el evento <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> por ejemplo para cerrar el server de forma segura. Puedes mirarte [Capturar KeyboardInterrupt](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/111029/15089).

En cuanto a tu error, abres tu archivo en modo texto (`"w+"`) pero intentas escribir bytes en el. El error en concreto se debe a que cuando haces `recibido + '\n'` estas intentando concatenar bytes (`recibido`) con una cadena `str` y por tanto con codificación "utf-8" (`'\n'`).

O bien decodificas la cadena que recibes antes de pasársela a `write`:

```
import socket
import signal
import sys


file = open("mensajes.txt", "w+")
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("127.0.0.1", 5550))
s.listen(5)


def keyboard_interrupt(signal, frame):
    file.close()
    print ("Adios")
    sc.close()
    s.close()
    sys.exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, keyboard_interrupt)


while True:
    print("Servidor iniciado. Pulse 'Ctrl'+'c' para salir")
    sc, addr = s.accept()
    while True:
        recibido = sc.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
        file.write(recibido + "\n")
        print("Recibido: ", recibido)
        nuestra_respuesta = input("Tu: ")
        sc.send(nuestra_respuesta.encode('utf-8'))
```

O abres el archivo en modo binario:

```
import socket
import signal
import sys


file = open("mensajes.txt", "wb+")
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("127.0.0.1", 5550))
s.listen(5)


def keyboard_interrupt(signal, frame):
    file.close()
    print ("Adios")
    sc.close()
    s.close()
    sys.exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, keyboard_interrupt)


while True:
    print("Servidor iniciado. Pulse 'Ctrl'+'c' para salir")
    sc, addr = s.accept()
    while True:
        recibido = sc.recv(1024)
        file.write(recibido + b'\n')
        print("Recibido: ", recibido.decode("utf-8"))
        nuestra_respuesta = input("Tu: ")
        sc.send(nuestra_respuesta.encode('utf-8'))
```

La línea `print("Recibido: ", recibido,"utf-8".decode("ascii"))` no es válida en Python 3. No se que pretendes con `"utf-8".decode("ascii")` pero `str` (cadena "utf-8" en Python 3) no tiene el método `decode` como es lógico, otra cosa es que se usara Python 2.